# Changing the draggable attribute

Tags: javascript

I am making an maths puzzle page for kids.
The answers are in s which drag over the questions.
When an answer is used, I would like to disable the dragging of the specific answer.
I can "dim" the answer and prevent it from being dropped but thus far have found no way of preventing the  from being dragged.

Please help.... I would *prefer* not to use JQuery if possible

```
function handledrop(elt, evt) {

        //Dim THE DRAGGED ITEM 
        dragitem.style.opacity=0.4;  //***********This works
        dragitem.style.hidden="true";//***********This doesn't or any variation I an think of
                                     //***********dragitem.draggable="false"
                                     //***********dragitem.style.draggable="false"
                                     //***********dragitem.draggable="false"

        dragitem.ondrag =  "donothing()";
        dragitem.ondragstart="donothing()" ;
        }
```

Comment: If you _don't_ want to use jQuery, I would recommend tagging the question with JavaScript instead.

Comment: @JasonP ya, that's quite funny

Answer (score 0):

You can set the draggable to false as

```
document.getElementById('you_id').setAttribute('draggable', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
function handledrop(elt, evt) {

        //Dim THE DRAGGED ITEM 
        dragitem.style.opacity=0.4;  //***********This works
        dragitem.ondrag =  "return false;";
        dragitem.ondragstart="return false;" ;
}
```

In this you'll prevent the drag function previously set on the element.

Comment: I don't think the OP is using jQuery UI for drag and drop. I think is using HTML drag and drop